# Render multiple boxes in THREE.js and store in 3 dimensional array

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have written code to render a 16x16 grouping of boxes in THREE.js.

```
const drawGroup = () => {

    const blockConstant = 16

    // Positions
    for (let x = 0; x < blockConstant; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < blockConstant; y++) {
            for (let z = 0; z < blockConstant; z++) {
                const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
                mesh.position.set(x, y, z)
                scene.add(mesh)

                const lines = new THREE.LineSegments(edgesGeometry, edgesMaterial)
                mesh.add(lines)
                //console.log(mesh.position)
            }
        }
    }
}

drawGroup()
```

I would like to now store all the positions for the blocks in the group in a 3 dimensional array. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Just create an array inside an array, inside an array.

```js
const blockConstant = 16

// Start an array in the x-dimension
const positions = [];

// Positions
for (let x = 0; x < blockConstant; x++) {

    // Create a new array inside x-dimension with y-dimensions
    positions[x] = [];

    for (let y = 0; y < blockConstant; y++) {

        // Create a new array inside y-dimension with z-dimensions
        positions[x][y] = [];

        for (let z = 0; z < blockConstant; z++) {

            // Now you can access the 3D-array to assign whatever value you wish
            positions[x][y][z] = `${x}, ${y}, ${z} \n`;
        }
    }
}
console.log(positions.toString());
```

As an aside, keep in mind that a `16 x 16 x 16` block will yield 4096 meshes, which will most likely give you a pretty low framerate. I recommend you use [some sort of instancing method](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_instancing_dynamic) to render all the blocks in a single drawcall, and improve framerate issues.